# Can't access Twitter/Facebook/Youtube after upgrade to Windows 10 from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, youtube, facebook, twitter

I have upgraded my Windows 7 x64 to Windows 10. The problem I have is that I can't access `Twitter/Facebook/Youtube` on **all my browsers**. They just **timeout** on connecting. I have disabled my anti-virus. cleaned DNS cache. just done almost everything.

What should I do?

Thanks for help

Comment: You don't have access only to these social networking sites or any other website. Have you tried opening google or yahoo.?

Comment: @CZAbhinav, yes they open, but slowly. my network runs slowly overall

Comment: just check what option you have selected `obtain DNS automatically` or `use following dns address`. If you are using `automatic obtain IP address` then `obtain DNS automatically` should be selected